# Assign certain colors to certain dots of a scatter plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I need to assign certain colors to certain dots of a scatter plot. I've written something like this:

```
Color = zeros(size(Check,1),1);

for i = 1:size(Check,1)
    if Check(i) == 0
        Color(i) = [0.3010  0.7450  0.9330];
    elseif Check(i) == 1
        Color(i) = [0.4660  0.6740  0.1880];
    elseif Check(i) == 2
       Color(i) = [0.9290  0.6940  0.1250];
    elseif Check(i) == 3
        Color(i) = [0.8500  0.3250  0.0980];
    elseif Check(i) == 4
        Color(i) = [0.6350  0.0780  0.1840];
    end
end

scatter(x,y,Color,'filled','s');
```

Beware that 'x', 'y', 'Color' and 'Check' have the same dimension (15000 x 1). Numbers in 'Check' are either '0', '1', '2', '3', or '4'. I just need to assign five different colors to my scatter plot based on the numbers I have in 'Check' matrix. The colors should be those that I used in the code as I need this plot to match with another bar chart I already have. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scatter plots in MATLAB have the `CData` property that can be used to assign colors to plots. This can be an `nx3` matrix, as you have in your `Color` variable. However, the `CData` property can also be a vector, and you can use the `colormap()` function!

Start off like adjpayot did:

```
Color = [0.3010  0.7450  0.9330;
0.4660  0.6740  0.1880;
0.9290  0.6940  0.1250;
0.8500  0.3250  0.0980;
0.6350  0.0780  0.1840];

% Assume you have a figure open already
scatter(x,y,'filled', 'CData', Check);
colormap(Color);
colorHandle = colorbar();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works great. But do you know how I could add a legend to my scatter plot for these 5 different colors?

Comment: Hmm, this is a messy way to do it, but I can't find a way to do it more cleanly. Basically, we need to create 5 different scatter plots overlaid, so that the legend entries refer to these 5 different plots.

`Figure;`
`hold on;`
`scatter(x(Check==1), y(Check==1),'filled','Cdata', Check(Check==1));`
`scatter(x(Check==2), y(Check==2),'filled','CData', Check(Check==2))`
... do the same for 3-5
`hold off;`
`legend('1','2','3','4','5');`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried what you said, but it gives me only one color for the whole legend! Do you have any ideas on what's wrong? I use colormap(Color) as well but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Color`  to be a `Color = zeros(size(Check,1),3);`
That is because colors are RGB values, so need one number for each colour channel.
this means the rest of your code needs to be:

```
Color = zeros(size(Check,1),3);

for i = 1:size(Check,1)
    if Check(i) == 0
        Color(i,) = [0.3010  0.7450  0.9330];
    elseif Check(i) == 1
        Color(i,:) = [0.4660  0.6740  0.1880];
    elseif Check(i) == 2
       Color(i,:) = [0.9290  0.6940  0.1250];
    elseif Check(i) == 3
        Color(i,:) = [0.8500  0.3250  0.0980];
    elseif Check(i) == 4
        Color(i,:) = [0.6350  0.0780  0.1840];
    end
end

scatter(x,y,Color,'filled','s');
```

If you want you can also get rid of the loop by doing:

```
Color=[0.3010  0.7450  0.9330;
0.4660  0.6740  0.1880;
0.9290  0.6940  0.1250;
0.8500  0.3250  0.0980;
0.6350  0.0780  0.1840]

scatter(x,y,Color(Check+1,:),'filled','s');
```

In that code I'm using `Check` to index the list of colours specified in `Color`. Adding another case is as simple as adding an extra colour to the array.